# Dino Ruby Gem - program stops responding on board att

Tags: ruby, arduino

I installed ruby 1.9.3 and the [dino gem](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-ruby-to-program-arduino--cms-21893) on windows, bootstrapped it (like the tutorial said, I resetted the arduino when uploading the generated and sketch and got a 'avrdude done. Thank you.' at the end) but got a problem when executing the blink code

```
# dino_sample.rb

require 'dino'

  board = Dino::Board.new(Dino::TxRx.new)
  led = Dino::Components::Led.new(pin: 13, board: board)

  [:on, :off].cycle do |switch|
    led.send(switch)
    sleep 0.5
  end
```

but more specifically this line

```
board = Dino::Board.new(Dino::TxRx.new)
```

the program stops responding and I can't even quit it with ^C
since it's my first attempt to use dino I have no idea of what went wrong, but I would guess the bootstrap was not done correctly